# How to import a jquery plugin in a vuecli3 project

Tags: jquery, vue.js, jquery-plugins

I am trying to import a jquery plugin into my project.
I keep getting the following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

the jquery plugin is not added via npm so I could possibly assume that might be what causes the problem.

Jquery itself is however imported and installed through npm. And I did test that it works.

I created a project using Vuecli3
I then managed to import and install jquery via npm.

Then I created a dir /js/slick.js for my jquery code where the file gets imported but the file does not detect jquery.

this works.

app.vue

```js
    export default {
        mounted() {
            $("body").html("This is Hello World by JQuery");
        }

    }
```

main.js

```js
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    new Vue({
      render: h => h(App),
    }).$mount('#app')
```

The following doesn't work, even though it picks up/detects the file.
(I also tried loading jquery locally)
(slick.js is just a simple hello world)

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    // window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    // window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    // var $ = window.jQuery;

    require("../js/slick.js");
    import slick from '../js/slick.js';
    export default {


    }
```

I am still new in the whole project setup scenario.

but I thought maybe I should perhaps add it to my dependencies in package.json

```
      "dependencies": {
        "core-js": "^2.6.5",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-draggable-resizable": "^2.0.0-rc2",
        "slick": "./js/slick.js"
      },
```

it didn't make any difference.

the js console error

> 

```
slick.js?a016:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at eval (slick.js?a016:1)
    at Object../src/js/slick.js (app.js:2270)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:724)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Item.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:2)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Item.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:840)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:724)
    at fn (app.js:101)
    at eval (Item.vue?12bc:1)
    at Module../src/components/Item.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:2247)
```

Answer (score 0):

go to your project directory in your terminal and write

```
npm install jquery
```

and in your App.vue, write

```
const $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;
```

Comment: I did try that.
I still receive the Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @Fanna1119 I have updated my answer, do you want to give that a try?

Comment: It still doesn't work. :(

and because it works in the mounted(as shown in the snippet), it makes no sense that it doesn't work with a basic import.
could it be related to one file maybe loading before the other?